# unoconv: raise Exception(stderrdata)

Tags: unoconv

I'm running a Tryton 3.4 ([tryton.org](http://www.tryton.org)) instance and trying to generate a report. This task is requires unoconv (which I have installed v.0.6) and libreoffice (also installed and recently updated).
Even so, when I try to generate the report (that should be converted from odt to pdf) I get the following error:

"

```
  File "/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 150, in _marshaled_dispatch
    response['result'] = dispatch_method(method, params)
  File "/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 179, in _dispatch
    res = dispatch(*args)
  File "/trytond/protocols/dispatcher.py", line 161, in dispatch
    result = rpc.result(meth(*c_args, **c_kwargs))
  File "/trytond/modules/account_invoice/invoice.py", line 2450, in execute
    res = super(InvoiceReport, cls).execute(ids, data)
  File "/trytond/report/report.py", line 144, in execute
    type, data = cls.parse(action_report, records, data, {})
  File "/trytond/modules/account_invoice_ar/invoice.py", line 706, in parse
    localcontext=localcontext)
  File "/trytond/modules/account_invoice/invoice.py", line 2479, in parse
    localcontext)
  File "/trytond/report/report.py", line 300, in parse
    data = cls.unoconv(data, report.template_extension, output_format)
  File "/trytond/report/report.py", line 320, in unoconv
    raise Exception(stderrdata)
Exception: None"
```

I also made myself sure that unoconv is on $PATH.
All other libraries and dependencies are installed and up to date (python3-UNO, uno-libs3, etc).

So I'm out of ideas of what could the problem be.
Anyone has a hint on what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the same issue as https://bugs.tryton.org/issue2703

Comment: Even the link may provide a useful solution, please summarize it here. Especially because a link may be unavailable when your post will be read.